# open js file in html button onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, buttonclick

I am currently working in HTML and JavaScript. I am Beginner. I want to open a javascript file in the onclick event of the button which is in my html file. is there any method to do this. kindly help me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean open a javascript file, what exactly is in this file and why would you need it to be opened?

Comment: What do you mean by open? You want to show the sourcecode within the browser? You want to download the sourcecode?

Comment: @Dray: Maybe you simply need to call some javascript function when button clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It think you mean it "Load" instead of open

You can 'Load' JS file dynamically using following code

```
  var fileref = document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  fileref.setAttribute("src", yourfilename)
```

Comment: Can be important in some cases add an attribute "charset".